# sift algorithm for opencv 4.1

Tags: python, opencv

I am executing statement `sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()`.
It is working fine with OpenCV 3.4 but I want to execute it with the OpenCV version 4.1.

I am getting the following error:

> Message=OpenCV(4.1.1) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv_contrib-4.1.1\modules\xfeatures2d\src\sift.cpp:1207: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'cv:

Comment: And which part of the error message don't you understand?

Answer (score 3):

As SIFT is patented in the USA to enable it in OpenCV you have to compile OpenCV from source with contrib modules and explicity set the flag `OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE` while configuring your project in CMake.

See this [question](https://answers.opencv.org/question/201938/how-can-i-set-opencv_enable_nonfree-cmake-option-and-rebuild-the-library-in-function-create/) for more information.